# SQlite with Windows 8 Metro apps

Tags: sqlite, microsoft-metro

I am trying to use an already created database(sqlite file) in Metro app. 
I am using C# and Sqlite-net. I have SQlite for WinRT.

Tried Tim Heuer approach which did not compile.
The await operator can only be used within an async method. Consider marking this method with 'async' modifier and changing its return type to 'Task'.
same for second time I am using await again.

Answer (score 1):

You may find my [`async`/`await` intro](http://nitoprograms.blogspot.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html) helpful.

In your specific case, I recommend that you do what the error message says: mark the method `async` and change the return type to `Task` or `Task<T>` (unless it is an event handler).

Comment: Thank you.I am using Async method. Following is the code - Windows.Storage.StorageFile seedFile = await Windows.Storage.StorageFile.GetFileFromPathAsync( Path.Combine(Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.InstalledLocation.Path, "SXXConf.sqlite")); await seedFile.CopyAsync(Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder);               Both await are errors .....

Comment: I'm having difficulty reading that. Please update your original question with the *complete* `async` method that is causing the error.

Comment: I found it. Thank you. Chaged the method which contained the code to async void instead of void only. It worked. I am new to this Visual sudio/C# progamming.   I can connect to my database. Can you help me find a link for retrieving data in Metro app and linking the data in metro app. Thank you!

Comment: I recommend you use `async Task` instead of `async void`. Regarding Metro, you probably want to load your data into a ViewModel in memory (e.g., an `ObservableCollection<T>`) and then use data binding. Google for MVVM (Model-View-ViewModel) and you'll find lots of hits.

Comment: Thanks Stephen. Let me try MVVM!